# How can I implement this kind of IO action?

Tags: debugging, haskell, io, monads, io-monad

I have the following datatype, which encodes arbitrary real numbers:

```
newtype ArbReal = ArbReal {approximate :: Word -> Integer}
```

I have the following function, which finds the limit of a converging sequence of real numbers:

```
inexactToReal :: (Word -> ArbReal) -> ArbReal
inexactToReal f = ArbReal $ \n -> let
    ArbReal g = f n
    in g n
```

I implemented a constant, the natural logarithm of ten:

```
ln10 :: ArbReal
ln10 = inexactToReal $ \n -> if 0 == n
    then 2
    else let
        halfN = ceiling (n % 2)
        a = inexactToReal $ \m -> go (2 * logBaseZ m 2) 1 (4 / 10 ^ halfN)
        in pi / (2 * a * fromInteger halfN)
  where
    go n a b = let
        newA = (a + b) / 2
        in if 0 == n
            then newA
            else go (n-1) newA (sqrt (a * b))
```

But this has some bugs. I think this falls in an infinite loop. So I wanted to turn it to a debugging routine. And that's where the problem is. Consider the following variant of `go` above:

```
debugAGM :: Word -> ArbReal -> ArbReal -> IO ArbReal
debugAGM n a b = let
    newA = (a + b) / 2
    in if 0 == n
        then putStrLn "Iteration complete." >> return newA
        else do
            putStrLn ("debugAGM iteration: n = " ++ show n)
            debugAGM (n-1) newA (sqrt (a * b))
```

This is too much of `IO`. There is no variant of `inexactToReal` that can handle this.

Yet consider this:

```
debugAGM :: Word -> ArbReal -> ArbReal -> (ArbReal, IO ())
debugAGM n a b = let
    newA = (a + b) / 2
    in if 0 == n
        then (newA, putStrLn "Iteration complete.")
        else let
            (x, action) = debugAGM (n-1) newA (sqrt (a * b))
            in (x, putStrLn ("debugAGM iteration: n = " ++ show n) >> action)
```

This is too little of `IO`. The `IO` action is parallel to the returned value. There is no variant of `inexactToReal` that can handle this.

In summary, I must somehow escapsulate `IO` so the followings will be achieved:

- The returned value, which is essentially a function, must be pure.
- Yet there must be also an `IO` action that depends on the potential argument of the returned function.

How can this be achieved? It's quite heartbreaking that an imperative language can do this easily.

Comment: Look at [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html), it's invaluable for debugging issues like this.   Audrey Tang described `Debug.Trace` as "a refreshing desert in the oasis of referential transparency"

Comment: I don't really understand the implementation of `inexactToReal`. If you take away the newtypes, and replace Word and Integer with type parameters, it's `inexactToReal :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> b; inexactToReal f x = f x x`. How does this correspond to finding the limit of a sequence?

Comment: Also, how does `ln10` typecheck? It seems to mix up ArbReal with numeric types often, but no Num instance is declared.

Comment: @amalloy I implemented `instance Num ArbReal`, but that involves too much of savage math to show here.

Comment: @amalloy The constructor `ArbReal` labels only Cauchy sequences with asymtotically fixed speed of convergence, so `inexactToReal` effectively calculates a limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
debugAGM :: Word -> ArbReal -> ArbReal -> Word -> (Integer, IO ())
debugAGM n a b p = let
    newA@(ArbReal f) = (a + b) / 2
    in if 0 == n
        then f p `seq` (f p, putStrLn "Iteration complete.")
        else let
            (x, action) = debugAGM (n-1) newA (sqrt (a * b)) p
            in x `seq` (x, putStrLn ("debugAGM iteration: n = " ++ show n) >> action)

ln10 :: Word -> IO ()
ln10 n = if 0 == n
    then putStrLn "2"
    else let
        halfN = ceiling (n % 2)
        f = \p -> debugAGM (2 * logBaseZ p 2) 1 (4 / 10 ^ halfN) p
        ArbReal g = pi / (2 * ArbReal (fst . f) * fromInteger halfN)
        in snd (f n) >> putStrLn (show (g n))
```

Comment: Those `seq` calls definitely don't do anything. Evaluating IO isn't the same as executing it.